# asp.net c# DetailsView DropDownList fails to Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, binding, detailsview

I've created a DetailsView that displays data based on a selected item from a GridView. When the DetailsView is under Edit Mode, it displays dropdownlists that contain data from a SQL databind. The data displays in the dropdownlist without issue, but fails to update. All other fields succeed.

The data is bound to the drop down via OnDataBound.
The idea is to populate the SelectedValue with the current data, and populate what it can be changed to. This works without issue. It simply fails to update.

I believe it has to do with syncing the control with the "an" parameter, but am at a loss at how to do so.

Front End Code pertaining to the issue:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="userDetails" runat="server" 
            Height="50px" 
            Width="400px" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="id" 
            DataSourceID="detailsSqlDataSource" 
            ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None"
            OnDataBound="userDetails_ItemEdit">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" width="125px"/>
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="first_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="last_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="user_name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="T" SortExpression="t">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="tEditDD" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("t") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="t1" Text="t1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="t2" Text="t2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="t3" Text="t3"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("t") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("t") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P" SortExpression="p">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="pEditDD" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("p") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="As" Text="As"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="An" Text="An"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Su" Text="Su"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Ad" Text="Ad"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("p") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("p") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="An" SortExpression="an">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="anEditDD" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("an") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("an") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Su" SortExpression="su">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="suEditDD" runat="server" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("su") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("su") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="E-Mail" SortExpression="email" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AL" SortExpression="al">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="alEditDD" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("al") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="As" Text="As"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="An" Text="An"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Su" Text="Su"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Ad" Text="Ad"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="alInsertDD" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("al") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="As" Text="As"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="An" Text="An"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Su" Text="Su"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Ad" Text="Ad"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("al") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="detailsSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPConnectionString %>" 

            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [users] SET [first_name] = @first_name, [last_name] = @last_name, [user_name] = @user_name, [t] = @t, [p] = @p, [an] = @an, [su] = @su, [email] = @email, [al] = @al WHERE [id] = @original_id">

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="usersGrid" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="user_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="t" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="p" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="an" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="su" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="al" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_user_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_t" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_p" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_an" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_su" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_al" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void userDetails_ItemEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (userDetails.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        AnDD();
    }
}

protected void AnDD()
{
    DropDownList anEditDD = userDetails.FindControl("anEditDD") as DropDownList;
    string userName = ((TextBox)userDetails.Rows[3].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CPConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    string currentAnSqlSelect = "SELECT an FROM users WHERE user_name='" + userName + "'";
    SqlDataReader currentReader;
    SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand(currentAnSqlSelect, con);
    currentReader = ccmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (currentReader.Read())
    {
        ListItem currentList = new ListItem();
        currentList.Text = currentReader["an"].ToString();
        errorLBL.Text = currentReader["an"].ToString();
        anEditDD.Items.Add(currentList);
    }
    currentReader.Close();

    string anSqlSelect = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE position='An'";
    SqlDataReader anReader;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(anSqlSelect, con);
    anReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (anReader.Read())
    {
        ListItem anList = new ListItem();
        anList.Text = anReader["first_name"].ToString() + " " + anReader["last_name"].ToString();
        anEditDD.Items.Add(anList);
    }
    anReader.Close();
    con.Close();
    anEditDD.Items.Add("N/A");
    anEditDD.DataBind();
    anEditDD.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "it fails to update", does that mean it actually generates a sql error message upon attempting to save, or it just doesn't save?  If it generates an error, what is the error?  If it just doesn't update, look at SQL Profiler and see what the update statement is that is getting sent to the server.

Comment: It fails to save. As I am not using a SelectedValue='<%# Bind("an") %>' statement, i don't believe the value is being passed and updated in SQL. I get an error when attempting to use both the aforementioned statement, and OnDataBound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Your update command appears to be part of the details view, and not part of any ObjectDataSource.  Can you confirm your markup above is correct?</strike>

**Edit**

In your `UpdateParameters` group, you aren't getting the values from the controls.  Try doing the following:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter />
    ...snip
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="an" ControlID="idOfWhateverControlHasTheUserSetValue" Type="String" />
    ...snip
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: That is from the asp:SqlDataSource for the DetailsView

Comment: Yeah but it is mixed in the middle of your DetailsView markup.  It would be very helpful if you cleaned up the markup above to resemble your existing code as closely as possible.  You can use 'snip' kind of hints to indicate where you've left out pieces that don't affect the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took your advice and did a little research about using the ControlParameter.

The fix was adding the following to the Update Parameters, and removing the auto-populated parameters for 'an'. Thanks for the help, Nick.

`<asp:ControlParameter Name="an" ControlID="userDetails$anEditDD" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String"  />`